# extracting content behind google analytics javascript

Tags: javascript, beautifulsoup

I'm searching for a way to automated access the link to the .gme file from a site like [this](https://www.ravensburger.de/produkte/kinderbuecher/tiptoi/tiptoi-wir-lernen-englisch-32904/index.html#tiptoiDownloadContainer) - nothing illegal here, just files for a kids toy. You access the file by clicking "Herunterladen" in the box with the text "Audiodatei manuell herunterladen". A sub window will pop up with a direct link to the .gme file ([WWW%20Englisch.gme](https://cdn.ravensburger.de/db/applications/WWW%20Englisch.gme) in this case).

I want to automate the download but my problem is I can't directly access the link from the source code of the page. The "Herunterladen" link has the attribute `onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Download_pdp', 'TipToi-Audio-Datei','32904');"` which I assume to be javascript for using google analytics. Is there a way to resolve this into the html code to extract the link? The filenames are very inconsistent so I can't generate the filename from the website informations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That won't actually download the file, that is simply sending code to Google Analytics so they can track what was downloaded.

Comment: you are right. However I want to get the html from the sub window to parse the link.

Comment: look at the source code,find the ID of the link that has that onclick you will then see the event handler for that link, which includes the URL that is actually being opened.

Comment: @imvain I'm a noob in javascript, how do I access or "see" the event handler? the onclick is `onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Download_pdp', 'TipToi-Audio-Datei','32904');"`, so I guess the ID is 32904.

Comment: there are actually two on it. First goto the source code and find the link that has that onclick, then look at it and it has an ID. Grab that id and search the source code until you find that ID within a click hander.

Comment: @imvain2 thank you very much! Could you please write your comments as an answer so I can accept and upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link has two event handlers, one via `onclick` and one later down in the code. If you look at the source code of the page, and find that onclick link you will see it has an ID. Simply search for that ID until you find the click handler tied to that ID. Within the event handler it shows the URL of the modal that is popped up.